# How to capture value of data-network property in a data layer variable?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, google-tag-manager

I am trying to capture the value data-network 'facebook' of the SVG icon in Google Taga Manager using a data layer variable.

[image: HTML code for the element]

The code for the data layer element that I came up with is as follows

```
gtm.element.parentElement.previousSibling.parentElement.parentNode.attributes.0.nodeValue
```

this data layer variable should get value just as 'facebook'.

I am probably a little far off right now. Any ideas how I would be able to do that?

I am open to creating a custom javascript variable which will get the data-network value of the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the value facebook in a data layer variable using Google Tag Manager using the below value -

```
gtm.element.parentElement.attributes.1.nodeValue
```